# Limiting the results of drop-down in Google Sheets

Tags: drop-down-menu, google-sheets, offset

I work as an operations manager at at small business and I'm trying to set up an order sheet that is easy for the salesman to use. In the order sheet, I've used the OFFSET function to refer to a master list containing customers and prices. Under Customer, I type the customer and it draws it from the master list via an auto-complete drop-down. The same happens with the product.

Here is the order sheet:

[Order Sheet Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvyQw.png)

My issue is I'll begin typing in the product e.g. 'prawn'. We have over a dozen prawn lines, but a particular customer will only take one. All of the other prawn results have no prices for that customer. However, the auto-complete function will offer up all the 'prawn' results.

In the Master list, I've entered prices for only the products that the particular customer uses. Take a look at what the Master List looks like:

[Master List look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXuXT.png)

Without an excellent memory of what customer wants what, it's an exercise in trial and error. In the above example, I could type 'topside' and if I select the wrong one, no price comes up.

This is frustrating.

I was hoping for a way to limit the auto-complete so that when I type 'prawn' or 'topside' for that customer, it only comes up with auto-complete fields that have the price in it. Can anyone help? Or does anyone know of any work-arounds? I'd be really thankful, the current order system is quite difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will do what you want. It is a little difficult to tell from your sample data. It uses google apps script and sheet names and/or columms may need to be changed in the script for your data. I am attaching a sample spreadsheet you can copy then try. You will have to approve the script in the copy you make.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var cust=e.value //The value of the edited cell
  var sh=e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName()//Name of the active sheet.
  var col=e.range.getColumn()//The edited column
  var r=e.range.getRow()//The edited row
  var row=e.range.offset(0,1).getA1Notation()//Cell A1 notation of cell in same row one column to the right.
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetName()//Name of active sheet
  var s1=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")//Variables for sheets
  var s2=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")
  var s3=ss.getSheetByName("TEMP")
  var rng=s2.getDataRange().getValues()//Customer/Products

  if(sh=="Sheet1" && col==1){//If sheet1 is active sheet and Customer (column A) is edited.

  var array=[]//Array to hold customers products
  for (var i=0;i<rng.length;i++){
    if(rng[i][0]==cust ){
      for(var j=1;j<rng[0].length-1;j++){
         if(rng[i][j]!="" ){//If customers product has $ entry add to Array.
          array.push([rng[0][j]])
   }}}}
   s3.clearContents()//Clear old product list from TEMP.
   s1.getRange(row).clearContent()//Clear product dropdown
   s3.getRange(1,1,array.length,1).setValues(array)//Set new customer product list in TEMP.
   drop(row,cust)// Call drop function to build new dropdown.
}
if(sh=="Sheet1" && col==2){//If sheet1 is active sheet and Product (column B) is edited.
  var cust1=e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue()//Get customer in A
  var prod=e.range.getValue()//Get selected product
 for (var i=0;i<rng.length;i++){//Get the customer/product price
    if(rng[i][0]==cust1 ){
      for(var j=1;j<rng[0].length-1;j++){ 
         if(rng[0][j]==prod){
          price=rng[i][j]
          s1.getRange(r,5).setValue(price)//Set the price in column E
         s1.getRange(r,2).clearDataValidations() //Remove the data validation dropdown in column B
        }
      }}
}}}
 function drop(row,cust){
   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
   var s3=ss.getSheetByName("TEMP")
   var s1=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
   var cell = s1.getRange(row);//set validation in B
   var ocell=s1.getRange(row).offset(0, -1).getValue()//evaluate value in A
   var cellVal=cell.getValue()
 if(ocell==cust){ 
   var lr= ss.getSheetByName("TEMP").getLastRow()
   var range = ss.getSheetByName("TEMP").getRange(1, 1, lr, 1)
   var rule =  SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range).build();//Build the dropdown
 cell.setDataValidation(rule)}//Set the validation rules (Customers 
products)
 }
```

Test spreadsheet:
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u86sdf1_mO-Mv7hQM_hRZl3Gma-Y2lsu9ZvxSW4jA1U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Ed,

This works perfectly! I applied your script to my spreadsheet and it does what I wanted it to do.

The only thing I would ask is whether you could make the 'price' column the 5th column across instead of the 3rd. Or if you could tell me which are the variables that affect that. Ideally I'd use the 3rd and 4th columns for carton/kg counts.

Thanks heaps,

Comment: @Petar I changed the script to put the Price in column E. I changed s1.getRange(r,5).setValue(price)//Set the price in column E from (r,3) to (r,5). If this answers your question, please approve the answer by ckicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. Thanlks.